# NodeJs - Module version mismatch. Expected 48, got 46. bindings.js

Tags: node.js, npm

I have node 6.12.3 and npm 3.5 installed on my machine. I am facing issue while executing the app. There is some issue with one of the node module. I tried `npm update` `npm rebuild`, even I deleted node_modules and reinstalled all the modules but no luck. Find the error snapshot below:

```
Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 48, got 46.
at Error (native)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at bindings (/home/Me/Documents/W/node-app/src/server/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:81:44)
at Object.<anonymous> (home/Me/Documents/W/node-app/src/server/node_modules/node-expat/lib/node-expat.js:4:32)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand from the error message, the node version which you've installed in your machine has a module version of 46 which could be any of Node.js 's 4.X.X releases.

You should completely uninstall your current version and should consider installing Node.js which should be any of 6.X.X

For more info, Checkout this release chart => https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Hope this helps.